# The Sisters' Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This is a riddle that I know from back in high school. So here it goes:

> Two sisters are we
>
> One dark, one fair
>
> We live in twin towers
>
> And make quite a pair
>
> One from land
>
> And one from sea
>
> The fairer sister
>
> Which is she?

Simply, who or what is the fairer sister?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fairer sister is:

> Salt

Two sisters are we
One dark, one fair

> Salt is white, pepper is black

We live in twin towers
And make quite a pair

> Salt & Pepper shakers

One from land

> pepper comes from peppercorns, which are the dried fruit of the [black pepper plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pepper)

And one from sea

> Sea Salt

The fairer sister
Which is she?

Comment: Correct. I knew pepper was from a plant but for some reason I hadn't thought of the peppercorn haha.

Comment: Salt, being white, must be the "fairer sister".

Comment: why is it the fairer sister?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Fair is also a term that means pale. As in "She was of fair skin.", so salt being white in nature is a pale color, as such, it is fair.